# WebSocket has become very slow after switching to WSS

Tags: nginx, websocket

I made a basic chat app based on WebSockets to send messages. It was working fine until I switched to WSS. Sending requests through HTTP was fast. However, when using HTTPS, messages now take time to send and the socket keeps disconnecting more often.

Here's my Nginx configuration file in case I'm doing something wrong here:

```kotlin
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    # SSL Certificate Configuration
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  # new line
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";  # new line
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Can you assist me with this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration seems correct for handling WebSocket connections through HTTPS.

Try some quick checks, then most obvious, then things that should be working, but you never know. You may choose a different order

Try it on a few different browsers to see if it’s browser specific.

Check the server logs for both Nginx and your WebSocket server for error messages or warnings related to WebSocket connections. When checking logs, always think about things that haven’t been reported.

Try Ping/Pong i.e. if it’s closing, it may be a result of no data flowing.  Build in a send using websocket.send periodically to keep the session alive.  It could be the client closing the session or if it’s a mobile, could kill the session.  [A question was asked about keeping a session alive](https://www.google.com/) which hasn’t been answered, but has a couple of comments.

It may be worth double-checking your client-side WebSocket implementation to ensure its correctly configured to use WSS (secure WebSocket) and you're connecting to the correct WSS URL. Also, that your SSL certificate (cert.pem) and private key (key.pem) are valid and correctly configured.

Check if there are any network or firewall issues that might be affecting secure WebSocket connections i.e. settings to allow traffic on ports 443 and 3000.

Comment: I already did all what you've mentioned. Nothing works. The socket keeps disconnecting, and messages take time to send.